# calculate mean for groups

Tags: stata, mean

I'm doing a research about SATs scores by cities. I have every city coded. Is there any way to ask Stata to calculate the mean for each city without having to type the city-code? Not having to write: `sum if city==1` and then `sum if city==2`, but instead that Stata takes all the people with the same city code and calculates the mean?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this post on stack overflow has some code it in you could use:

[Using if qualifier with egen in Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577808/using-if-command-with-egen-in-stata)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The essence is `egen mean_sat_score = mean(sat_score), by(city)` is a way to get city-wide means into a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to skin a cat, but something like this would do it:

```
table city_name, contents(mean sat_score count sat_score) row
```

This also gives you the number of individuals with non-missing scores in each city as well as an overall average. Type `help table` for other options.

`sum` also takes a `bysort` prefix, so `bysort city_name: sum sat_score` also works, but the output is less compact than with `table`.

Unlike the `egen` approach, neither of these will create a variable that stores the city-specific means. It will only show you the output on the screen.