# Stata - calculate average of everyone in group except current observation

Tags: stata

I want to calculate the average of all members of the group I am in, but not include myself in the average.  Suppose that the group variable is called `group` and I want to take the average of `val1` by `Group`, excluding myself.  The new column I wish to create is `avg`.  The data looks as follows (with the correct values of `avg` inputed so you can see what I mean).

```
Obs   Group   val1    avg
1     A       6       8
2     A       8       6
3     B       10      13
4     C       4       4
5     C       2       5
6     C       6       3
7     B       12      12
8     B       14      11
```

If I wanted to include myself in the calculation it would be straightforward.  I would just do:

```
bysort Group: egen avg = mean(val1)
```

But how do I implement this with the wrinkle that I don't include myself?

Comment: Please try to look at existing resources. This has been a FAQ since 2001 (http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-variables-recording-properties/) and as such an answer is findable through `search`.

Comment: Question and answer have no connection to **sorting**, so tag removed.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577808/using-if-qualifier-with-egen-in-stata Same point about looking at existing resources....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is looping through all observations:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
Obs   str1 Group   val1    avg
1     A       6       8
2     A       8       6
3     B       10      13
4     C       4       4
5     C       2       5
6     C       6       3
7     B       12      12
8     B       14      11
end

list, sepby(Group)

*----- what you want -----

encode Group, gen(group)

gen avg2 = .

forvalues j = 1/`=_N' {

    summarize val1 if group == group[`j'] & _n != `j', meanonly              
    replace avg2 = r(mean) in `j'
}

list, sepby(group)
```

Another way is using `egen` functions:

```
<snip>    

*----- what you want -----

encode Group, gen(group)

bysort group: egen totval = total(val1)
by group: egen cval = count(val1)
generate avg2 = (totval - val1) / (cval - 1)

list, sepby(group)
```

There is a nice article available on the web that covers this topic:

The Stata Journal (2014)
14, Number 2, pp. 432–444,
*Speaking Stata: Self and others*, by
Nicholas J. Cox.

Comment: The key is that average of every other value is (total of all - this value) / (count of all - 1), but missings complicate this, so watch out.